# Show parent of grandchilderen

Tags: wordpress

I have a little problem.

I have one parent, 1 child, 1 grand child, 1 great grand child and 1 great great grand child as page structure in wordpress.

The code that i use is this:

```
function wpb_list_child_pages_popup() { 

    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )

    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
else
    $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

if ( $childpages ) {

    $string = '<ul id="child-menu">' . $childpages . '</ul>';
}

return $string;

}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages_popup', 'wpb_list_child_pages_popup');
```

I only see the parent of that current child page or great grand child page.

How can i use this code on time to make sure that de current page shows 2 parents up in the list?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php global $post; $thispage = $post->ID; // grabs the current post id from global and then assigns it to thispage ?>
        <?php $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$thispage."&sort_column=menu_order"); // gets a list of page that are sub pages of the current page and assigns then to pagekids ?>
        <?php if ($pagekids) { // if there are any values stored in pagekids and therefore the current page has subpages ?>
            <ul>
                <?php wp_list_pages("depth=1&title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$thispage); // display the sub pages of the current page only ?>
            </ul>
        <?php } elseif($post->post_parent)
                $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); if ($children) { // if there are no sub pages for the current page ?>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks but the thing is i use a shortcode in my templates. how can i merge these 2 to make it work through the shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function wpb_list_child_pages_popup() { 

    global $post; 
    $thispage = $post->ID;
    $pagekids = get_pages("child_of=".$thispage."&sort_column=menu_order"); 

    if ($pagekids) { // if there are any values stored in pagekids and therefore the current page has subpages
        echo '<ul>';
            wp_list_pages("depth=1&title_li=&sort_column=menu_order&child_of=".$thispage); // display the sub pages of the current page only
        echo '</ul>';
    } elseif($post->post_parent){
        $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0"); 
    }

    if ($children) { // if there are no sub pages for the current page 
        echo '<ul>';
        echo $children;
        echo '</ul>';
    } 
}

add_shortcode('wpb_childpages_popup', 'wpb_list_child_pages_popup');
```